# How to install redis 7.2 on amazon linux 2023

Tags: amazon-linux, redis

How to install redis 7.2 on amazon linux 2023. When I do the default installation it only install redis 6.x.

Comment: I had several of this kind of questions before, and while discussing problems with the answer to these questions, it's been *multiple times* late in the process that the asker realizes that well, maybe they shouldn't be using a version of a software that's not officially supported by their server operating system. So, let me ask this very clearly upfront: What's the **technical** reason you need redis 7.2 instead of the official 6.2.14? (knowing that would be necessary for recommending an installation method, anyways.)

Comment: we are start a new project which requires redis. reading about redis 7 it they seem to have better performance. Also more importantly redis 6.2 is reaching EOF in Aug 24 2024. would prefer not go with a version which is reaching EOF very soon. https://docs.redis.com/latest/rs/installing-upgrading/product-lifecycle/

Comment: So, then don't deploy that on amazon linux directly, but run it in a container as anyone else